# DataGrid not showing in .Droid (Uno-platform)

Tags: c#, wpf, uno-platform

I made DataGrid that correctly displays data in .Wasm and .UWP, but on .Droid app it doesn't show anything (header or body). The calling to my API works and data is correctly sent to .Droid. I store it in a list and set list as ItemsSource of my DataGrid.

This shows list filling:

```
list = await ApiService.GetList();
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
```

UserPage.Xaml:

```
<Page
...
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <controls:DataGrid 
        x:Name="dataGrid1" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto" Margin="12"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn  
                Width="SizeToCells"
                Binding="{Binding id}" 
                FontSize="20" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
                Width="SizeToCells"
                Binding="{Binding name}" 
                FontSize="20" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
                Width="SizeToCells"
                Binding="{Binding role}" 
                FontSize="20" />
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

I have installed Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls and Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.**DataGrid** on .Droid project. I followed [documentation](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-community-toolkit.html?tabs=tabid-vswin) but can't seem to find the solution.